# Reasonable size of file send to server from Android device

Tags: android, http

I know this question does not have a specific answer but I believe the experience of fellow developers might be useful to the community.

I want to send a file to server from Android device, given unreliable and slow internet connection on this devices (in most part of the world).

**My Question**

What should be the maximum size of file I should attempt to send from the device to the server reliably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is quite broad and there are several parameters which will influence the answer:

1) What is the average internet speed for your users? It varies a lot (from EDGE to 4G, which which could have 100 to 1000 times difference in speed).

2) Will your used charged per megabyte? If so, it's not smart to upload huge amount of data

3) What type of information are you trying to send? As example, if it's text entered by user, most likely you don't need to worry about size at all (because a user won't be able to enter megabytes of text). If it's a video - you may need to apply some limits.

My recommendation would be - let a user decide. Choose some default maximum size (let say 10Mb). And make it configurable, so if a user tries to upload file bigger than maximum, you will show some notification that it exceed maximum size and that user can change it.

Comment: I agree Victor the question lacks specific answer. Let us assume worst case scenario - Edge and leave charges apart. Is 10MB possible?

Comment: I would say worst case scenario you can get let say 56kbit/second internet. In such case, 10Mb will take about 25+ minutes in flawless conditions. I would say it's too much. Try to set 1-2 MB as maximum size (it will allow to upload file within reasonable amount of time - 5 minutes).

Comment: And just to iterate again. Give ability to a user to decide whether he/she is ok waiting 10-25 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

use [`DownloadManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html),

> The download manager is a system service that handles long-running
>   HTTP downloads. Clients may request that a URI be downloaded to a
>   particular destination file. The download manager will conduct the
>   download in the background, taking care of HTTP interactions and
>   retrying downloads after failures or across connectivity changes and
>   system reboots.

i think you should be more concerned about bandwidth usage than reliability. short downloads can fail or be paused / delayed because of intermittent connectivity also. the important thing is that you recover from the errors and report status to the user about what's happening.

a smart app would have a "download over wifi only" option, that is probably set to true by default. also, a "this app transfers large amounts of data" warning might be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, I am taking about uploading data to Server not downloading it from Server.